# Validating list columns with respect to other column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list with two columns

[image]

In platform column, user should not be able to enter Cobra again for internal speaker, `Title` is Single line of text and `Platform` is **Lookup**.

Can we do it using column validation.

[image]

Comment: This means concatenation of value in Column A and B should be unique, however, we don't have that validation OOB. Are both of these text type? Can you ask your users to enter combined value (with a separator) in a single column and then split in two calculated columns? Not a very good solution though!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SP2013.

Your question is a bit confusing but I would go with using CSR. With CSR you basically have full control over your edit and new forms by using Javascript. You can implement your custom validation logic with it.

To get you started:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a